# Any gotchas replacing global const char[] with constexpr string_view?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, string-view

Our team is working with a 10+ years old C++ code base and recently switched to a C++17 compiler. So we are looking for ways to modernize our code. In a conference talk on YouTube I heard the suggestion, to replace `const char*` global strings with `constexpr string_view`.

Since we got quite a number of such `const char*` global string constants in our code, I want to ask if there are any gotchas or potential issues we need to be aware of?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These issues might be worth being aware of:

1. `std::string_view` doesn't need to be `null`-terminated. So if you replace some `const char*` by `string_view` and replace the construction of a previously `null`-terminated `char*` substring by a `string_view` via `std::string_view::substr`, you can't pass the underlying pointer to an API that expects a `null`-terminated string. Example (without UB, but that is easily constructable, too):

   ```
   void legacy(const char *str) {
      std::printf("%s\n", str);
   }

   constexpr std::string_view sv1 = "abcde";
   constexpr std::string_view sv2 = sv1.substr(0, 2); // view on "ab"

   legacy(sv2.data()); // Not intended: prints "abcde"
   ```
2. While you can implicitly construct a `std::string` from a `const char*`, you cannot do that with a `std::string_view`. The idea is that a deep copy shouldn't happen under the cover, but only when explicitly requested. Example:

   ```
   std::map<std::string, int> m;
   constexpr std::string_view sv = "somekey";
   constexpr const char *old = "somekey";

   m[old] = 42; // works as expected
   m[sv] = 42; // fails to compile
   m[std::string(sv)] = 42; // be explicit, this is ok
   ```

   Depending on the existing usage of the global `const char*` instances in your project, this behavior might require manual intervention at various places.

Comment: that non-zero termination is definately a gotcha - auch. Now I need to go through our SVs. I suppose you would do `std::string(sv).c_str()` instead for passing to API ?

Comment: @darune That's an option, but then the lifetime assumptions of the API should be checked, right?! If you go with `someLegacyFct(std::string(sv).c_str())` and this backend somehow stores the pointer...

Comment: that is correct - only with that lifetime assumption

Comment: The second issue is "luckily" not going to be a big deal for us. Our company framework has it's own string class (I know...), with an explicit `const char*` constructor. So explicit construction of `std::string` from `string_view` would just be consistent in our case.